# List item menu's custom action on content type (only SPD2010)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-actions, custom-action

Is it possible to have a custom action List Item Menu in a document library on a specific content type, created in SPD 2010? 
In code I know is possible, but I'd rather try it out in SP Designer. 
Also, is it possible to enable specific security rights during its creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the two solutions, powershell and also VS2010 feature, both tested: http://zoraradosavlevici.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/add-list-item-menu-custom-action-to-a-specific-content-type-sp-2010/

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible.

Open the document library in SPD. You will have "Custom Action" button on the ribbon, where you can select "List Item Menu" custom action:

[image]

Then, on the form which appears, use vertical scrollbar (many people don't notice it's there) to scroll the contents of the form down. You will see "Rights" box there:

[image]

Unfortunately it's just a plain text field, you will get no hints of what should be there. Fortunately I can tell you that :) You must use values of the [SPBasePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) enumeration there. AFAICR, you can define several values, separating them by ",".

Btw, another trick here is that you can use `javascript: /* put your js here */` in the "Navigate to URL" box.

Well, as you can see, the interface is not very obvious, but nevertheless it exists :)

Comment: Andrey, thanks a lot! And do you know how I can link it to a specific content type? My document library has 2 content types assigned to it.

Comment: This is not possible from SPD :(

Comment: Thank you Andrey, I needed the confirmation for this.        I take the easy approach and create a powershell script for the list item menu. This way I can set the RegistrationType to ContentType and also set the Rights mask in the same time. I'll post it after testing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andrey's answer...

You can use Javascript to find the content type for the selected documents, after the menu item is selected.

Put this in your "Navigate to Url" field in the custom action.

```
javascript:if (GetListItem('{ListId}', '{ItemId}', function (item) { if (item.get_item("ContentTypeId").get_typeId() == "{YOUR CONTENT TYPE ID}") { doIt(); } }));
```

and put this function in your master page or a form html webpart on your page

```
function GetListItem(ListID, ItemID, onSuccess) {

  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

    this.context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.web = this.context.get_web();
    this.list = this.web.get_lists().getById(ListID);

    this.context.load(this.list);

    this.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

        this.item = this.list.getItemById(ItemID);
        this.context.load(this.item);

        this.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

            onSuccess(this.item);

        }), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));

 }, 'sp.js');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert(args.get_message());
}
```

then whatever you want to run on a specific content type put in here

```
function doIt() {
  alert();
}
```

Tested in SP2010 Foundation.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I'll go with a powershell script for this, since I don't have the rights to change the SharePoint page.